# createjs - end label animation detection

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs, detect, tweenjs

I have some tweens create with Adobe AnimateCC and, this animation have 3 labels:

from console i can get it:

```
elm.children[0].timeline._labels    
Object {animation_1: 0, animation_2: 31, animation_3: 62}
```

The issue is: if i trigger animation_1, will trigger animation_1, 2 and 3.
if i trigger animation_2, will trigger animation_2 and 3.

How I can detect the final of every single label, to set up a call back when this label animation is finished?

```
elm.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay("animation_1");
```

then detect when this label is finish.